# Why must constructing an object of class type 'someClass' with a metatype value use a 'required' initializer?

Tags: swift

```
class Animal {
    class func generate() -> Animal {
        return self()
    }
}
```

The compiler complains **constructing an object of class type 'Animal' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer**

I can understand this. If I write a subclass like this:

```
class SubAnimal: Animal {
    let head: Int
    init(head: Int) {
        self.head = head
        super.init()
    }
}
```

It will inherit `Animal`'s class method `generate()` but won't inherit its default initializer `init()`. So `SmallAnimal.generate()` actually calls `SmallAnimal()`, but `SmallAnimal` doesn't have an initializer `init()`! Of course this is what the compiler want to prevent.

What confuses me is a similar problem.

```
class someClass {

}
let anotherClass = someClass.self
let anotherObject = anotherClass()
```

The compiler still complains **constructing an object of class type 'Animal' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer**.

This time, I cannot understand. `anotherClass` is a **metatype value**, but what bad result will be caused?

I know how to solve this problem, adding `required init() {}` is the solution. But I really want to know the reason for the second case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider the case where we also have a subclass:

```
class SomeClass {

}

class SomeSubclass : SomeClass {

}
```

If you store the class type in a variable:

```
var anotherClass = SomeClass.self
```

The variable `anotherClass` is of type `SomeClass.Type`.

You can later assign this variable to a subclass:

```
anotherClass = SomeSubclass.self
```

This is valid because `SomeSubclass.Type` is a `SomeClass.Type`. At this point, `anotherClass()` would fail if the initializer is not implemented in the subclass. This is what the compiler is protecting against.

In your sample code, this is impossible: you used `let` instead of `var` so changing the type is impossible. It may be that the safety checks just aren't nuanced enough to notice this.

Comment: Great answer. Perhaps `let anotherClass: SomeClass.Type = SomeSubClass.self` is more concise?

Comment: `anotherClass`'s type is `SomeClass.Type`, so we use `SomeClass`'s initializer. But it's indeed a `SomeSubClass`, and `SomeSubClass` may not inherit `SomeClass`'s initializer. This is how the bad result comes out.