# Constructing an object of class type 'ClassName' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer XCode8 Swift 3 changes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm struggling with this particular error as a result of XCode 8 swift 3 changes, and can't find anywhere a detailed explanation as to why this is happening.

Error:

**Constructing an object of class type 'PermissionScope' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer**

In Method:

```
public convenience init() {
    type(of: self).init(backgroundTapCancels: true)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/32166077/611055

Answer (score 17):

i think it means you should add the world 'required'

```
class PermissionScope {

   required init(backgroundTapCancels : Bool){

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TomV,
I guess why below thing worked, is that from conv init you must call designated initializer. And also you cannnot call conv init directly from some other class as initiializer. So you might have been called this conv init from same class from some other init method due to which self is available to call further init.

Answer (score 0):

This compiled:

```
public convenience init() {
    self.init(backgroundTapCancels: true)
}
```

Comment: A `convenience` initializer is meant to act as a secondary initializer that, in turn, calls the designated initializer, whereas the alternative is to replace the designated initializer with your own. There is a pretty good explanation at https://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-swift-convenience-initializers/

Answer (score -2):

self is different in instance method and class method, you can see it through the auto completion of Xcode. In instance method, self’s type is SomeClass while in class method, it’s type is SomeClass.Type.

The compiler complains constructing an object of class type ‘SomeClass’ with a metatype value must use a ‘required’ initializer

How to understand this? If I write a subclass like this.

See the full explanation here:
http://blog.fujianjin6471.com/2015/08/31/why-does-constructing-an-object-with-a-metatype-need-a-required-initializer.html